# sound ByteArray---->Sound object

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays

I have a byteArray of recorded sound.

But how can I transfer the ByteArray data back to a real Sound object?

I know that I can pass the ByteArray to an SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA listener , but that way I would have to keep the raw ByteArray and pass it every time the sound plays ... but I'd rather like a real Sound object in the end to work with

--> I need the reverse function of `Sound.extract(ByteArray, ...)` !

Answer (score 2):

Have you check this function of Sound in Flash Player 11?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#loadCompressedDataFromByteArray%28%29

you can load byteArray to Sound Object Directly.

Answer (score 0):

The docs on [`Sound`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html) say:

> In Flash Player 10 and later and AIR 1.5 and later, you can also use
>   this class to work with sound that is generated dynamically. In this
>   case, the Sound object uses the function you assign to a sampleData
>   event handler to poll for sound data. The sound is played as it is
>   retrieved from a ByteArray object that you populate with sound data.
>   You can use Sound.extract() to extract sound data from a Sound object,
>   after which you can manipulate it before writing it back to the stream
>   for playback.

I don't see any other interface for creating a `Sound` object from a `ByteArray`. You could potentially write your own class implementing `Sound`, and allow this class to abstractly play a `ByteArray`, but I don't see any native way of playing bytes directly other than the `SAMPLE_DATA` method.